# Can't get handlebars to work with dynamic templates

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am very stuck. Tried everything I could think of to solve this issue, but I feel as though it is just something wrong with my JSON. When I build a dynamic template, I'd like to insert some variables for the send. As you can see in the example, simply just adding the first name in the handlebars. However, when I send tests using postman, I can not for the life of me get the first_name to display. I've tried so many different options in the JSON and nothing seems to work. Here is where I am currently at, omitting the first_name obviously. Any help on how to format this I would very much appreciate it.

```
{
  "from": {"email":"example@example.com"},
      "template_id":"ID HERE"
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email":"recipient@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried 100 different variations of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think that using that JSON is mainly for when you're using the API to send an email with a template. You then provide the JSON data as `dynamic_template_data` and it is populated in the email template.

`first_name` is a reserved field and substitution tag which lets you use any reserved or custom field data you've added to Marketing Campaigns to dynamically generate unique content for each recipient of your email. One common example is adding a recipient's first name to the body (or even the subject line) of your email.

The data that populates your Substitution Tags will come from the information you have stored about each contact.

You can work with substitution tags with the [code editor](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#using-substitution-tags-with-the-code-editor) or [design editor](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#using-substitution-tags-with-the-design-editor).

Let me know if this helps at all!